# DBeaver right-click on database and Tools -> Execute script: how to specify which schema?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

As stated in the question, in DBeaver when I right-click, choose Tools -> `Execute script` and if there are many schemas available it doesn't let me enter the schema where I wish to execute the script. This is a shared database with schema for other teams and I don't want to risk destroying other schemas.

How can I specify the right target schema for running the script?

Comment: The schema that the objects are created in is determined by the schema qualification of the object names or in the absence of that the schema order in the `search_path` setting.  Just be aware a explicit schema qualification of an object will override the `search_path`. In other words this is going to require careful examination of the script contents. Your best bet is to execute it in an test/empty database to verify.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks a lot for your help, I found a promissing way ... marking my desired schema as default schema, ran it but it failed because DBeaver's execute script implementation is based on the `psql` tool which I don't have access to.

Comment: Even if you marked a schema as default and you had a working `psql` the objects in the script may not end up there if they are explicitly named for another schema that does exist in the database.